# Get near by locations from google place api in android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am working on one of my project in android in which I am using Google Place API for finding the location based on text. my question is how to get location which is near to my current location?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=

E.G:- if I search "Domminoz Pizza" then google place API should return with all "Domminoz Pizza" and related searches near by my location not half across the country.

Comment: refer this link. https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search .if you pass proper location and details , then google will give your the exact details that you expecting.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Signare. you saved my valuable time.